# How to get params in twig file

Tags: symfony, parameters, get, twig

how can i use $_GET params in TWIG file like using PHP and alerting with JS.

URI-> ?comment=added...

in TWIG,

```
    if($_GET['comment'] == "added"){
     ...echo '<script>alert("in TWIG file!");</script>';
    }
```

Comment: i solved myself. 
           
         {% if app.request.query.get('comment') == 'added' %}
                        <script>alert('Added!');</script>
                    {% endif %}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

hope it will help you

```
{% if app.request.get('comment') == "added" %}
    <script>alert("in TWIG file!");</script>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're really trying to achieve, the "Symfony way" of showing confirmation messages would be to use "Flash Messages":

YourController.php:

```
public function updateAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(...);

    $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // do some sort of processing

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'notice',
            'Your changes were saved!'
        );

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(...));
    }

    return $this->render(...);
}
```

Your TwigTemplate.twig:

```
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
    <div class="flash-notice">
        {{ flashMessage }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This way you have multiple advantages:

1. Redirecting after action prevents form reloading.
2. Message cannot be triggered from outside.
3. Flash messages are only fetched once.

See the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" solution would be use your controller to provide a function to Twig rather than switching on the querystring. This will be more robust and provide better security:

Controller:

```
function someAction()
{
    $params = array('added' => false);
    if( /* form logic post */ )
    {
          //some logic to define 'added'
          $params['added'] = true;
    }

    $this->render('template_name', $params);
}
```

view:

```
{% if added %}
    <script>alert('added');</script>
{% endif %}
```

The reasoning is that this is more secure (I can't trigger the alert by just browsing to the url), it maintains all business logic in the controller and you're also able to handle any errors - e.g. if you browse to foo.php?comment=added and there is an error wherein your comment isn't added, the user will still receive the alert.